# Java: limit formKeyTyped to a single key?

Tags: java

I currently have this code:

```
private void formKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              
    URL url;
    try {
        url = this.getClass().getResource("jj_jason.wav");

        Clip clip;

        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais;

        ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch(IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

    }
}
```

The problem is that this plays the "jj_jason.wav" file when no matter which keyboard key is pressed. I'd love to let this only happen if one specific key is pressed, lets say 'T'. I've been looking for info on howto do that, but have failed in finding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [evt#getKeyCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) and compare that to one of the `VK_` constants. They describe so-called "virtual key codes". A virtual key code is a keyboard key that has been pressed, rather than a character generated by the combination of one or more keystrokes (such as "A", which comes from shift and "a").

Alternatively, you can look at [evt#getKeyChar()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29) for the exact character.